# hypeledger fabric JavaScript-application node app.js does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to the blockchain field and I try to run sample network from Hyperledger network follow [this](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html) documentation  . I started download the prerequisite and get every things right .

The network is working and deploy it using JavaScript after all the channel and deployment I cd into the JavaScript-application to run the app.js as the documentation said but I got this error

```
node app
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:944
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'pkcs11js'
Require stack:
- D:\fifthLevel\blockchain\hyperledger\try-fabric-network\go\src\github.com\FatimaAlmashhor\fabric-samples\asset-transfer-basic\application-javascript\node_modules\fabric-common\lib\impl\bccsp_pkcs11.js
- D:\fifthLevel\blockchain\hyperledger\try-fabric-network\go\src\github.com\FatimaAlmashhor\fabric-samples\asset-transfer-basic\application-javascript\node_modules\fabric-common\lib\User.js
- D:\fifthLevel\blockchain\hyperledger\try-fabric-network\go\src\github.com\FatimaAlmashhor\fabric-samples\asset-transfer-basic\application-javascript\node_modules\fabric-common\index.js
- D:\fifthLevel\blockchain\hyperledger\try-fabric-network\go\src\github.com\FatimaAlmashhor\fabric-samples\asset-transfer-basic\application-javascript\node_modules\fabric-network\lib\logger.js
- D:\fifthLevel\blockchain\hyperledger\try-fabric-network\go\src\github.com\FatimaAlmashhor\fabric-samples\asset-transfer-basic\application-javascript\node_modules\fabric-network\lib\impl\query\query.js
- D:\fifthLevel\blockchain\hyperledger\try-fabric-network\go\src\github.com\FatimaAlmashhor\fabric-samples\asset-transfer-basic\application-javascript\node_modules\fabric-network\lib\transaction.js
- D:\fifthLevel\blockchain\hyperledger\try-fabric-network\go\src\github.com\FatimaAlmashhor\fabric-samples\asset-transfer-basic\application-javascript\node_modules\fabric-network\lib\contract.js
- D:\fifthLevel\blockchain\hyperledger\try-fabric-network\go\src\github.com\FatimaAlmashhor\fabric-samples\asset-transfer-basic\application-javascript\node_modules\fabric-network\lib\network.js
- D:\fifthLevel\blockchain\hyperledger\try-fabric-network\go\src\github.com\FatimaAlmashhor\fabric-samples\asset-transfer-basic\application-javascript\node_modules\fabric-network\lib\gateway.js
- D:\fifthLevel\blockchain\hyperledger\try-fabric-network\go\src\github.com\FatimaAlmashhor\fabric-samples\asset-transfer-basic\application-javascript\node_modules\fabric-network\index.js
- D:\fifthLevel\blockchain\hyperledger\try-fabric-network\go\src\github.com\FatimaAlmashhor\fabric-samples\asset-transfer-basic\application-javascript\app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:774:27)   
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\fifthLevel\blockchain\hyperledger\try-fabric-network\go\src\github.com\FatimaAlmashhor\fabric-samples\asset-transfer-basic\application-javascript\node_modules\fabric-common\lib\impl\bccsp_pkcs11.js:27:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)        
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)   
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19) {       
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'D:\\fifthLevel\\blockchain\\hyperledger\\try-fabric-network\\go\\src\\github.com\\FatimaAlmashhor\\fabric-samples\\asset-transfer-basic\\application-javascript\\node_modules\\fabric-common\\lib\\impl\\bccsp_pkcs11.js',
    'D:\\fifthLevel\\blockchain\\hyperledger\\try-fabric-network\\go\\src\\github.com\\FatimaAlmashhor\\fabric-samples\\asset-transfer-basic\\application-javascript\\node_modules\\fabric-common\\lib\\User.js',
    'D:\\fifthLevel\\blockchain\\hyperledger\\try-fabric-network\\go\\src\\github.com\\FatimaAlmashhor\\fabric-samples\\asset-transfer-basic\\application-javascript\\node_modules\\fabric-common\\index.js',
    'D:\\fifthLevel\\blockchain\\hyperledger\\try-fabric-network\\go\\src\\github.com\\FatimaAlmashhor\\fabric-samples\\asset-transfer-basic\\application-javascript\\node_modules\\fabric-network\\lib\\logger.js',       
    'D:\\fifthLevel\\blockchain\\hyperledger\\try-fabric-network\\go\\src\\github.com\\FatimaAlmashhor\\fabric-samples\\asset-transfer-basic\\application-javascript\\node_modules\\fabric-network\\lib\\impl\\query\\query.js',
    'D:\\fifthLevel\\blockchain\\hyperledger\\try-fabric-network\\go\\src\\github.com\\FatimaAlmashhor\\fabric-samples\\asset-transfer-basic\\application-javascript\\node_modules\\fabric-network\\lib\\transaction.js',  
    'D:\\fifthLevel\\blockchain\\hyperledger\\try-fabric-network\\go\\src\\github.com\\FatimaAlmashhor\\fabric-samples\\asset-transfer-basic\\application-javascript\\node_modules\\fabric-network\\lib\\contract.js',     
    'D:\\fifthLevel\\blockchain\\hyperledger\\try-fabric-network\\go\\src\\github.com\\FatimaAlmashhor\\fabric-samples\\asset-transfer-basic\\application-javascript\\node_modules\\fabric-network\\lib\\network.js',
    'D:\\fifthLevel\\blockchain\\hyperledger\\try-fabric-network\\go\\src\\github.com\\FatimaAlmashhor\\fabric-samples\\asset-transfer-basic\\application-javascript\\node_modules\\fabric-network\\lib\\gateway.js',
    'D:\\fifthLevel\\blockchain\\hyperledger\\try-fabric-network\\go\\src\\github.com\\FatimaAlmashhor\\fabric-samples\\asset-transfer-basic\\application-javascript\\node_modules\\fabric-network\\index.js',
    'D:\\fifthLevel\\blockchain\\hyperledger\\try-fabric-network\\go\\src\\github.com\\FatimaAlmashhor\\fabric-samples\\asset-transfer-basic\\application-javascript\\app.js'
  ]
}
```

I do not know exactly from where the error is coming the node seems fine and all the packages I can see them inside the node_modules and package-lock.json

```
node -v
v16.3.0
npm -v
7.17.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the fabric node-sdk has broken the feature where having a C compiler was optional, now it's mandatory but because pkcs11 is still declared as optional the node-sdk will not fail to install but will fail to run as you have seen. You are going to either have to

1. install the microsoft C compilers + python v3 and re-install (or rebuild) the fabric node-sdk node module which will then be able to build the pkcs11 native library (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools on how to install the compilers and python)
2. specify a specific version of the fabric node sdk (It looks like it was broken in 2.2.4 so 2.2.3 should work) so erase the node_modules directory and update package.json to specify exactly the version of fabric-network (ie put in `2.2.3` with no preceding characters such as ^ or ~) and run npm install again
3. Use a linux desktop distribution instead of windows as they tend to include the necessary pre-reqs to build a native node library

The final thing to note is that you are using a version of node and npm which aren't supported. You should use node 12 or node 14 as these are the lts releases supported

Comment: Sorry for delay I was trying to make it work but I am still facing a lot of issues, first the windows-build-tools keep stopping . and the npm could not install yarn for some reason . And I am using Windows 10 . I want the Hyperledger work on the Docker images and container . Thank you for your helping

Comment: I would recommend then that you fix the version of fabric-network, fabric-ca-client to 2.2.3 in your package.json rather than try to install the C compilers on windows. There is a fix coming to the node-sdk but it's not been published yet

Comment: they are already  2.2.3 :( sorry for bothering you .

Comment: 2.2.8 has been published now which fixes the problem, you will still get messages when you run npm install (that's expected) but the application won't fail now because of no pkcs11js module